# Basic functions (sum, len, etc.) with recursively-flattened arguments

Tags: python, recursion

Based on the excellent answers provided for [my previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86842/deep-recursive-join-all-any-sum-len), I've thoroughly revised my attempt at "deep" versions of `all`, `any`, etc. It uses the recommended encapsulated flattening function, and streamlines some unnecessary stuff.

```
def flatten(*sequence, preserve=False):
    for item in sequence:
        try:
            assert hasattr(item, '__iter__') and not isinstance(item, str)
            if preserve:
                next(iter(item))
        except (AssertionError, StopIteration):
            yield item
        else:
            for i in item:
                yield from flatten(i, preserve=preserve)

def dsum(*args, preserve=False, s=''):
    if any(isinstance(item, str) for item in flatten(args)):
        return s.join(map(str, flatten(args, preserve=preserve)))
    iter_ = flatten(args, preserve=preserve)
    first = next(iter_)
    return sum(iter_, first)

def dlen(*args, preserve=False, s=False):
    return sum(len(arg) if s and isinstance(arg, str) else 1 for arg in flatten(args, preserve=preserve))
```

The `flatten()` function is "public" and intended to be accessed from outside the module. It handles an arbitrary number of arguments and generates each non-iterable element (strings are treated as non-iterable). If the keyword argument `preserve` is set to `True`, empty iterables are preserved.

I am not aware of any way to use `if` to test whether a generator/iterable has any items to `yield` - is there such a way? If not, is my use of `assert` an acceptable way of turning the `if` statements into exceptions, or is it better to use `if... raise`, or something else entirely?

The `dsum()` function adds together all the items yielded by `flatten()`. If `preserve` is `True`, empty iterables are preserved. If at least one item is a string, everything is converted into a string and joined, connected by the optional `s` argument. If there are no strings, all items after the first are added onto the first item. If there aren't any strings and there are items that can't be added, the function fails, which I find acceptable.

The `dlen()` function finds the total length of all the items yielded by `flatten()`. If `preserve` is `True`, empty iterables are preserved and counted as a length of 1. Strings are counted as objects of length 1 unless the optional keyword argument `s` is `True`, in which case their actual lengths (number of characters) are counted.

I have removed `dany()`, `dall()`, etc. because they were just wrappers around `flatten()` with zero additional logic.

Test suite (passes):

```
from deep import *
import datetime as dt

assert dsum([1,2], 3, '1','2','3','456', []) == '123123456'
assert dsum([1,2], 3, '1','2','3','456', [], preserve=True) == '123123456[]'
assert dsum('a', 'b') == 'ab'
assert dsum(1, [2,[3,[4,[5],[]]]]) == 15
# dsum(1, [2,[3,[4,[5],[]]]], preserve=True) # can't sum int with preserved list
assert all(flatten(1, 1, [1, []]))
assert not all(flatten(1, 1, [1, []], preserve=True))
assert all(flatten(1, 1, set()))
assert not all(flatten(1, 1, set(), preserve=True))
assert list(flatten((1, 1, []))) == [1,1]
assert list(flatten((1, 1, []), preserve=True)) == [1,1,[]]
assert dsum(dt.timedelta(3), dt.timedelta(4), s=dt.timedelta()) == dt.timedelta(7)
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what is your use case for these functions?

Comment: It feels more natural to be able to send multiple arguments to `join()` instead of just a single iterable - in other words, I kept doing `''.join(string1, string2)` and getting a traceback. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things for the `flatten` function:

First, your code won't work when an item is an iterator and `preserve=True`, since it will consume the first sub-item in the iterator, making the next `for` loop skip the first item.  A better approach would be to run the `if` test, then check if `i` has been defined.  If it hasn't, then you can yield the item.  I personally use a short-circuit `continue` to avoid nesting too deeply, but this again is personal preference.

Second, you really shouldn't use `assert` here, you can just use an `if` test to short-circuit.

Third, this may be a personal thing, but I don't like explicitly testing if something is a `str`.  For example, if you don't want to flatten a `str`, you probably don't want to flatten a `bytes`, either.  I prefer to duck-type for a `str`-like object using `hasattr(item, 'lower')`, which tests for the `lower` method.  This should really only be present on `str`-like objects, although I admit it isn't perfect.

Fourth, some of your other functions would be easier if you include an option to split strings.

Fifth, just because an item has the `__iter__` method does not mean it is iterable.  It may have something in the method that raises some except.  So it is better to test if it raises an except if you try to make it iterable.

For the `dsum` function:

I don't see the point of `preserve` here.  How would adding an empty iterable to anything do anything?

Second, I would really put the string-handling function as an option.  So perhaps if `s=False`, then you can raise an error since the items cannot be combined.  And I would use a more descriptive name (`sep` is common).

Third, again this won't work if any items are iterators, since it runs through them twice.  There is no way around this other than to convert the items to a list or something like that.

Fourth, I think a generator expression is easier to understand than a map.

For `dlen`:

If you include the option I mentioned above to flatten strings, this becomes much simpler.  You just pass that argument along to the `flatten` function.

So here are the resulting functions

```
def flatten(*sequence, preserve=False, flat_str=False):
    for item in sequence:
        try:
            iter(item)
        except BaseException:
            yield item
            continue

        if hasattr(item, 'lower') and (not flat_str or len(item) == 1):
            yield item
            continue 

        for i in item:
            yield from flatten(i, preserve=preserve, flat_str=flat_str)

        if not preserve:
            continue
        try:
            i = i
        except NameError:
            yield item


def dsum(*args, preserve=False, sep='', flat_str=False):
    if sep is False:
        items = flatten(args, preserve=preserve)
        first = next(items)
        return sum(items, first)

    items = list(flatten(args, preserve=preserve, flat_str=flat_str))
    if any(hasattr(item, 'lower') for item in items):
        return sep.join(str(x) for x in items)
    return sum(items[1:], items[0])


def dlen(*args, preserve=False, flat_str=False):
    return sum(1 for arg in flatten(args, preserve=preserve, flat_str=flat_str))
```

Comment: 1: Oops. 2: Sounds fine. 3: Good point - any other types like these? 4: In what way? 5: I see. -- `dsum`: 1: So that `all(flatten([1],[]))` works like `all([[1],[]])`. 2: What's the purpose of `sep=False`? Just to suppress the "if there's a string, convert all to string" behavior? - `s` wasn't always a separator (and may now be `False`), so `s` might be more appropriate than `sep`. 3: How does `list` conversion affect performance here? 4: Either way, I guess. -- What's the purpose of `flat_str`? -- `if sep is False` should be `if sep == False`.

Comment: 3: no, that is the main one.  4: I explain that in the `dlen` section.  `dsum`: 2: one-character arguments are discouraged.  3: It will hurt performance, but there is no other way I am aware of to make this work reliably.  4: I explain `flat_str` in the fourth point for the first function.  Empty strings are also `False`, so `'' == False` is `True`, while `'' is False` is `False`.

Comment: Actually, although `bool('') == False` evaluates to `True`, `'' == False` evaluates to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

That is an inappropriate use of an assertion. You should only assert conditions that *you know must be true*. Furthermore, you must not rely on assertions for correct execution of your program, since [assertions can be disabled](//stackoverflow.com/a/1273233/1157100).

I would also add that I find the execution flow in `flatten()` difficult to follow.

Comment: How about `raise`, replacing `assert hasattr(item, '__iter__') and not isinstance(item, str)` with `if not hasattr(item, '__iter__') or isinstance(item, str): raise StopIteration`?

Comment: Mixing exceptions, conditionals, and loops is very confusing. Can't you find some way that doesn't use exceptions at all?

Comment: I'm not sure how else to check whether an iterator/generator contains elements. Is there some equivalent to `if len(mylist)` that works even on generators like `(item*2 for item in mylist)`?